# Using Katalon studio with Chrome Portable

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I need help running Katalon studio with Chrome portable.

I am using ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 and Chrome Portable Version 75.0.3770.100 which I downloaded from portableapps.com

I have configured Katalon studio to use the portable version as seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

When I run the Katalon tests or try to record, the webdriver throws the following error:

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'JHBPWM467086', ip: '10.110.43.144', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: CChromeDriver

I have tried running Katalon as an admin and I have tried different supported Chrome drivers and I get the same error.

Is it possible to use Katalon with portable chrome ? If so, what configuration items am I missing to get it working ?

Thank you in advance for any help. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Katalon is unable to find the browser. You will need to set path to chromedriver manually:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path-to\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Hi @mate-mrše, Thank you for responding. I think I might be doing something wrong on my side. I tried adding the line of code at the start of the script as well as on the chrome settings inside Katalon but I am getting the same error. Did I add it in the wrong place perhaps ? (I am super new to Katalon)

Comment: Did you provide a correct path in place of "path-to\chromedriver.exe"?

Comment: Hi @mate-mrše, I pointed it to the chromedriver.exe in katalon configuration. I double checked it.

Comment: @Marcel-Is-Hier I once had this issue, but only when running Katalon as non-administrator. Sorry, don't know why is this happening. You might try asking on forum.katalon.com.